# Samsung Galaxy S4 misaligns the Actionbar Icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm implementing a visual design for an app, and it turns out that the Galaxy S4 misaligns the actionbar home icon, as demonstrated in the screenshot:

[image]

The screenshots were taken using the exact same APK file on both devices. The purple guideline sits at 16dp from the left, and it is quite important to the rest of the screen layout. The S4 adds another 8dp or so. This extra margin makes the home icon really look out of place.

I've tried a bunch of other Samsung phones at different resolutions/densities (Galaxy S3, Galaxy S4 Mini, Galaxy Ace) and these all align the icon correctly at 16dp.

I'd chalk it up to Android fragmentation and move on, but the marketshare of the Galaxy S4 is so big that I can't really ignore the issue. Has anyone else encountered this, and found a fix?

Comment: Confirmed the same issue on Galaxy S3 with the 4.4.2 update. Really really annoying.

Comment: It could be a problem with your styles, the `ActionBar` can sometimes be a little tricky in that regard, but most likely Samsung just messed the `ActionBar` up. First I would test if a negative margin fixes the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem once. I had     'actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); But I also had something else which I cannot recall right now that made that arrow dissappear. Give it a go...

Comment: Did you tried with action bar sherlock?

Comment: Sherlock delegates to the "native" actionbar if the OS version has one.

Comment: can you show your actionbar layout?

Comment: This space does not show up for me in the Google play app, or in the gmail app on the S4. So it is most likely in your actionbar layout

Comment: The action bar layout is taken from the host OS, there is no such layout in my app, so I guess I don't understand your question. If you want to know, it's here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/action_bar_home.xml. Samsung is probably providing their own version of this layout or of the ActionBarView.java file, but since it's not open source, who knows. I can findViewById the home button and hack around in its LayoutParams, but I am still hoping for something elegant, for a more civilized age.

Comment: @Barend I am trying to understand which ActionBar you are using. Since others apps seem ok on the G4, it is most likely related to your app. Are you using the Support library ActionBarActivity? Or Sherlock? Or targeting only new versions and using native action bar? Can you post the AppTheme and other related definitions from styles.xml, as well as your icon ?

Comment: @yaoh The spacing is incorrect in all the Google apps as well on my S3 with 4.4.2 and both I and OP don't use a custom view in the ActionBar.

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue on my Galaxy S4 (SCH-I545) in any of the system apps, nor in any of my apps. Additional info would be helpful - are you using the AndroidManifest.xml to set your icon? Are you using android:icon, android:logo, or android:label?

Comment: Just a thought: if anyone's got a rooted S3/S4, perhaps comparing view hierarchies may give some insight. I.e. are there any differences in the hierarchies? If not, how about the various view property values etc? ALternatively, it may be interesting to determine whether custom ROMs suffer the same issue?

Comment: Which version of Android is the offending S4 running?

Comment: I don't get why everyone is commenting this does not occur on their S4.

I was really hoping on finding a sollution to this, but I see that every single app on the S4 does this.

I have a Moto G, Nexus 7 and S4 in front of me, only the S4 screws up. I guess I'll have to keep it like that.

Comment: I've since found out that if you `findViewById()` the home button, then grab its parent, then grab the first child (the up indicator, whose R.id is hidden, ([layout xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/action_bar_home.xml))), you can see that the negative right margin on the up indicator is gone. I have not been able to fix it yet.

Comment: @MikeM. I don't have it fixed yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is pretty self-explanatory. It first checks if the current device is a Samsung Galaxy S4 model, based on the [list found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Samsung_Galaxy_S4). If it is, it then looks for the relevant `View`s based on the `ActionBar`'s layout and the `home` `ImageView`'s relative position in the hierarchy. It then shifts them *left* by the (positive) `offset` parameter. It also checks if a Custom `View` is displayed, and shifts that as well. The only change is to the `View`s' `x` coordinates, so it should work with any theme or style.

```
private static final String SAMSUNG = "SAMSUNG";
private static final String[] S4_MODELS = {
    "GT-I9506", "GT-I9505G", "SGH-I337", "SGH-M919",
    "SCH-I545", "SPH-L720", "SCH-R970", "GT-I9508",
    "SCH-I959", "GT-I9502", "SGH-N045", "SGH-I337M",
    "SGH-M919V", "SCH-R970X", "SCH-R970C"
};

private void adjustGalaxyS4(int offset)
{
    if (isGalaxyS4())
        shiftHomeView(offset);
}

private boolean isGalaxyS4()
{
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER.toUpperCase();
    String model = Build.MODEL.toUpperCase();

    if (SAMSUNG.equals(manufacturer) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(model))
    {
        for (String m : S4_MODELS)
            if (model.contains(m))
                return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private void shiftHomeView(float offset)
{
    try
    {
        View grandParentView = (View) ((View) findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent()).getParent();
        View upView = ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) grandParentView).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0);

        grandParentView.setX(grandParentView.getX() - offset);
        upView.setX(upView.getX() + offset);

        if ((getActionBar().getDisplayOptions() & ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM) != 0)  
            getActionBar().getCustomView().setX(getActionBar().getCustomView().getX() - offset);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Fail silently
    }
}
```

Comment: I had preferred something less blunt, but this is effective enough as a workaround. I'll have to make it a bit more generic, because it's not exclusively Galaxy S4's that misalign, so I'm going to try and detect the misalignment by the actual X coordinate vs. the expected X coordinate. It's funny, I had written something similar earlier, but I tried adjusting the view's layout params and couldn't get it to work with or without requestLayout(). Sometimes the simpler approach of just calling setX() is clearly more convincing.

Comment: in the end, we wound up using the MaterialMenu open-source library as a custom view in the ActionBar, sidestepping the issue entirely.