# Programmatically Modify ActionBarDrawerToggle Drawable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-drawable

Does anyone know a way to get the drawable that is used for the ActionBarDrawerToggle after setting it in the constructor by resource ID?  I am using a navigation drawer and I want to apply a color filter to the icon programmatically, but I can't figure out how to access it as a drawable.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: you mean the three strip image?

Comment: Yeah, that's the one.  I can set it from a static resource drawable ID, but I want to be able to get the icon drawable to do a .setColorFilter on the image at runtime

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do that, but if you look at my answer in the following link, it is represented by `upView` in the `shiftHomeView()` method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240439/samsung-galaxy-s4-misaligns-the-actionbar-icon/24980936#24980936

Comment: @MikeM. That works, but is so hacky.  I can't find another way though.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it (unless a better solution shows up).  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, IIRC, you might not have to "go that far out" in the hierarchy, but it'll still be hacky. Lemme check.

Comment: I'm doing a findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent().getChildAt(0) which appears to be working well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the framework's ID for that View is hidden, the only way I've found to access it is by walking through the hierarchy based on the Home View's position in it.

```
public ImageView getUpView()
{
    ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent();
    return (ImageView) parentView.getChildAt(0);
}
```

Comment: This approach won't work if you're using an ActionBarDrawerToggle from support.v7. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33554037/770068) for a method that works with support library 23.1.

Comment: Or [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279953/get-reference-to-drawer-toggle-in-support-actionbar/28280347#28280347).