# Color of animated ActionBarDrawerToggle in ActionBar

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

How can i change the color of  animated ActionBarDrawerToggle  icons in ActionBar, using AppCompat-v7 (v21)?
I tried this, but doesn't work. Thanks.

**myActionBarActivity.java**

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mLeftDrawer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
```

**values/styles.xml**

```
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
```

---

```
    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
```

**UPDATE:** solved, there was this entry `<item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">` in my theme which probably overlapped  `<item name="drawerArrowStyle">`. I removed it and now all works.

Answer (score 24):

This should work..

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@color/your_color</item>
    </style>
```

and in your parent theme..

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        .
        .
        .
</style>
```

Comment: Handle your drawer by using the setNavigationOnClickListener on the toolbar

Comment: Styling snippet is the same that i tried. Doesn't work. Thks.

Comment: are you using the actionbar or the toolbarAlso ActionBarToggle from support v4 is deprecated in v21..It is now imported from appcompat v7.Have you imported the right one??

Comment: I am using ActionBar of ActionBarActivity.

Comment: the code I have posted is working for me..my parent theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light and its working quite well for me..I have a red drawer icon nad a red arrow that spins in my proj

Comment: Yes, right imported: `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;`

Comment: Best solution I found it. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Since support library 24.1.0 you can now have access to `getDrawerArrowDrawable()`. So to change the color you just need to do this:

```
toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to do it programmatically as well, by taking advantage of the existing color methods in `DrawerArrowDrawable`. You just need to pass your own `DrawerArrowDrawable` to `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and keep a reference to the `DrawerArrowDrawable` so you can call its methods.

However, that constructor within `ActionBarDrawerToggle` currently has package-private access, so you need to add a class in the `android.support.v7.app` package to gain access to it.

Here's an approach that extends from `ActionBarDrawerToggle` to expose the color methods.

Place this class into /src/android/support/v7/app/:

```
/*
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.support.v7.app;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;
import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.graphics.drawable.DrawerArrowDrawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;

/*
 * Version of ActionBarDrawerToggle that exposes DrawerArrowDrawable's color methods.
 * Needs to be in android.support.v7.app in order to access a constructor in ActionBarDrawerToggle
 * which currently has package-private access.
 */
public class ColorableActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

    private final DrawerArrowDrawable mSlider;

    /**
     * Construct a new ColorableActionBarDrawerToggle.
     *
     * <p>The given {@link Activity} will be linked to the specified {@link DrawerLayout} and
     * its Actionbar's Up button will be set to a custom drawable.
     * <p>This drawable shows a Hamburger icon when drawer is closed and an arrow when drawer
     * is open. It animates between these two states as the drawer opens.</p>
     *
     * <p>String resources must be provided to describe the open/close drawer actions for
     * accessibility services.</p>
     *
     * @param activity                  The Activity hosting the drawer. Should have an ActionBar.
     * @param drawerLayout              The DrawerLayout to link to the given Activity's ActionBar
     * @param openDrawerContentDescRes  A String resource to describe the "open drawer" action
     *                                  for accessibility
     * @param closeDrawerContentDescRes A String resource to describe the "close drawer" action
     *                                  for accessibility
     */
    public ColorableActionBarDrawerToggle( Activity activity
                                         , DrawerLayout drawerLayout
                                         , @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes
                                         , @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes ) {
        this(activity, null, drawerLayout, null, openDrawerContentDescRes, closeDrawerContentDescRes);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new ColorableActionBarDrawerToggle with a Toolbar.
     * <p>
     * The given {@link Activity} will be linked to the specified {@link DrawerLayout} and
     * the Toolbar's navigation icon will be set to a custom drawable. Using this constructor
     * will set Toolbar's navigation click listener to toggle the drawer when it is clicked.
     * <p>
     * This drawable shows a Hamburger icon when drawer is closed and an arrow when drawer
     * is open. It animates between these two states as the drawer opens.
     * <p>
     * String resources must be provided to describe the open/close drawer actions for
     * accessibility services.
     * <p>
     * Please use {@link #ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity, DrawerLayout, int, int)} if you are
     * setting the Toolbar as the ActionBar of your activity.
     *
     * @param activity                  The Activity hosting the drawer.
     * @param toolbar                   The toolbar to use if you have an independent Toolbar.
     * @param drawerLayout              The DrawerLayout to link to the given Activity's ActionBar
     * @param openDrawerContentDescRes  A String resource to describe the "open drawer" action
     *                                  for accessibility
     * @param closeDrawerContentDescRes A String resource to describe the "close drawer" action
     *                                  for accessibility
     */
    public ColorableActionBarDrawerToggle( Activity activity
                                         , DrawerLayout drawerLayout
                                         , Toolbar toolbar
                                         , @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes
                                         , @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes ) {
        this(activity, toolbar, drawerLayout, null, openDrawerContentDescRes, closeDrawerContentDescRes);
    }

    /**
     * In the future, [Google] can make this constructor public if [they] want to let developers customize
     * the animation.
     * 
     * [If they make this constructor public, ColorableActionBarDrawerToggle could be in another package.]
     */
    <T extends DrawerArrowDrawable & DrawerToggle> 
    ColorableActionBarDrawerToggle( Activity activity
                                  , Toolbar toolbar
                                  , DrawerLayout drawerLayout
                                  , T slider
                                  , @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes
                                  , @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes ) {
        super( activity
             , toolbar
             , drawerLayout
             , (slider == null) ? slider = (T)new DrawerArrowDrawableToggle(activity, getActionBarThemedContext(activity, toolbar)) 
                                : slider
             , openDrawerContentDescRes
             , closeDrawerContentDescRes );

        mSlider = slider;
    }

    /*
     * Condensed (equivalent) version of the code in all the getActionBarThemedContext methods 
     * called by ActionBarDrawerToggle constructor as of 23.1.
     */
    private static Context getActionBarThemedContext(Activity activity, Toolbar toolbar) {
        Context context = null;
        if (toolbar != null) {
            context = toolbar.getContext();
        } else if (activity instanceof DelegateProvider) { // Allow the Activity to provide an impl
            final Delegate delegate = ((DelegateProvider) activity).getDrawerToggleDelegate();
            context = delegate.getActionBarThemedContext();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            final ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                context = actionBar.getThemedContext();
            } else {
                context = activity;
            }
        }
        return context;
    }

    /// Expose DrawerArrowDrawable's color methods

    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        if(mSlider != null) {
            mSlider.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        }
    }

    public void setColor(@ColorInt int color) {
        if(mSlider != null) {
            mSlider.setColor(color);
        }
    }

    @ColorInt 
    public int getColor() {
        if(mSlider != null) {
            return mSlider.getColor();
        }
        return 0;//Color.TRANSPARENT;
    }

    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        if(mSlider != null) {
            mSlider.setAlpha(alpha);
        }
    }
}
```

Then just use `ColorableActionBarDrawerToggle` instead of `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, and call its `setColor()` or `setColorFilter()` methods to change the color at run time:

```
ColorableActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
// ....
mDrawerToggle.setColor(0xffff0000); // make it red
```

Comment: Looks like methods will be added in support library 24.1.0 to make this possible without any workarounds: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203429