# ActionBarDrawerToggle v7 arrow color

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

When I try to change navigation drawer toggle color, only hamburger changes it, arrow keeps her native color. You can see it here -[image]

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListViewStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>
```

If I change parent theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light arrow changes her color to black. 
The following widget are used:
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color of animated ActionBarDrawerToggle in ActionBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250915/color-of-animated-actionbardrawertoggle-in-actionbar)

Comment: I have answered how to do it programmatically on another question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250915/color-of-animated-actionbardrawertoggle-in-actionbar/40164200#40164200). Please mark this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mDrawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getColor(R.color.drawer_toggle_color));
        } else {
            mDrawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.drawer_toggle_color));
        }
```

Comment: You can use drawerToggle.drawerArrowDrawable.color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white) to avoid the version checking

Answer (score 12):

Try using

```
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/your_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/your_color</item>
```

instead of your drawer arrow style.

To clear out my comment, try also:

```
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/My.ActionBar.Style</item>
```

and then:

```
     <style name="My.ActionBar.Style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/your_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/your_color</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: Arrow changed her color to white. Magic.

Comment: This used to work with me. Try pasting it into a `<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Your.Custom.ActionBar.Style</item>`

Comment: I finally noticed that `colorControlNormal` works only if you use the arrow icon provided into the SDK with the support library (namely,  `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha`). It won't work if you import the icon from elsewhere, because appcompat only tints its own drawables. If you want to use a different icon, then you can't tint it via style.

Answer (score 8):

Try this one to change color of DrawerArrow

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could set custom arrow or other icon using the method

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(Int drawable resource);
```