# Customizing the 'back' arrow color in Actionmode with appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

My main theme is based on `Theme.AppCompat.Light` as follows:

```
<style name="core" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    <!-- Material, Yo!-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_main_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/deep_purple</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <item name="theme">@style/my_toolbar_theme</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/my_drawer_arrow</item>
    <!-- Actionbar -->
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@null</item>
    <!-- Contextual Actionbar -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/my_actionmode_style</item>
</style>

<style name="my_drawer_arrow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle" >
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/theme_accent_color</item>
</style>

<style name="my_toolbar_style">
    <item name="android:id">@id/toolbar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:elevation" tools:ignore="NewApi">5dp</item>
</style>

<style name="my_actionmode_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionMode.Inverse" >
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/my_actionmode_title_style</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/my_actionmode_subtitle_style</item>
</style>

<style name="my_toolbar_style.gradient">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_gradient_bg</item>
</style>

<style name="my_toolbar_theme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
    <!-- Customize the toolbar here -->
</style>

<style name="my_actionmode_title_style" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/std_white</item>
</style>

<style name="my_actionmode_subtitle_style" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

In *actionmode* I'd like to see white title/subtitles with a white back arrow. I've been able to set the title and subtitle text colors to white, but the back arrow remains black. This issue only occurs in places where I'm using the SupportActionbar and not the toolbar (the back arrow in toolbar is white).

This is my toolbar in ActionMode.

[image: This is my toolbar in ActionMode]

This is the actionbar in ActionMode. Same phone, same app, same themes, just a different activity.

[image: This is the actionbar in ActionMode]

I can't find anything in the themes that would determine this color. According to the source, the icon is `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha`, which is white, so something must be tinting it. Where does this black-ish color come from?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861102/actionbardrawertoggle-v7-arrow-color

Answer (score 50):

To customize this using AppCompat:

In your app level theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/myclosebutton</item>
</style>
```

In the CloseButtonStyle:

```
<style name="myclosebutton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:tint">#ff0</item> <!-- whatever color -->
</style>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. It allows to change the color of the back arrow while in action mode without having to know what is the drawable being used. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks mate.. finally I found something that works...!

Comment: the best answer

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and I have solved it by explicitly declaring the icon I want to use in the style:

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ab_back</item>
```

Where @drawable/ab_back is provided by me.

This is not ideal, as I would like to correctly set the style and let it work inheriting the right colours from the parent theme, without the need of declaring so specific details. But, I feel everything around the *ActionBar, SupportActionBar, SherlockActionBar, ActionBarActivity, FragmentActivityWithASherlockSupportActionToolbar* is SO broken and bad engineered that I'm happy to solve it with a workaround.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to do that. There are quite a lot of discrepancies in the support libs. Enough to make Steve Jobs giggle in his grave every time someone says _Fragmentation_ ...

Answer (score 0):

Try "colorControlNormal" Property Like given Below in your "NoActionBar Theme"

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have best answer for this

```
 Spannable text = new SpannableString( mode.getTitle());
                    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)),
                            0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    mode.setTitle(text);
```