# Android: unable to change color of back arrow navigation icon

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm using new android appcompat toolbar.  I need to set the same custom color to both burger icon and back arrow icons.  Using drawerArrowStyle allows me to change burger icon but not the arrow. The issue is only on Lollipop devices, anything pre-lollipop is fine.

[image: Burger]

[image: Arrow]

Here is the code:

Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/my_primary"
    local:theme="@style/My.Toolbar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Style.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_primary</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
  </style>

    <style name="My.Theme" parent="Theme.Base">
       <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="My.Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
      <!-- color of the title text in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat theme:  -->
      <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/my_actionbartext</item>

      <!-- necessary to support older Android versions.-->
      <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/my_actionbartext</item>

      <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/my_actionbartext</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
            <item name="color">@color/my_actionbartext</item>
    </style>
```

I've tried using solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861102/actionbardrawertoggle-v7-arrow-color) but it didn't work.  Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change color of the back arrow in the new material theme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788464/how-to-change-color-of-the-back-arrow-in-the-new-material-theme)

Answer (score 2):

Just do this in your Activity/Fragment:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha, null));
        else
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha));

   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am also not able to update back arrow button after upgrading to 23.2.0 support library

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The path to the right solution for the problem I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788464/how-to-change-color-of-the-back-arrow-in-the-new-material-theme/26837072#26837072)

However this still didn't 100% work due to our use of DrawerLayout.  My colleague wrote an excellent post on the solution [here](http://gregshackles.com/changing-the-android-toolbars-back-arrow-color/)

Comment: Great link, I only had to change the Theme myself to set it up properly, but this brings up the point that when a Drawer is  used, it has an interesting effect against the drawables.

Answer (score 0):

It is the color of actionMenuTextColor. Add this line to your theme.

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">your color</item>
```