# Change the color of Navigation Drawer indicator icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I am using a toolbar in place of actionbar and i am also using a navigation drawer.My toolbar colour is black and i want my navigation drawer indicator colour to be white.So how to change the colour of the navigation drawer indicator or put a custom navigation indicator in v7.Can any one please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color of animated ActionBarDrawerToggle in ActionBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250915/color-of-animated-actionbardrawertoggle-in-actionbar)

Comment: I have answered how to do it programmatically on another question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250915/color-of-animated-actionbardrawertoggle-in-actionbar/40164200#40164200). Please mark this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try creating this style in your `styles.xml`.

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And, then add it to you AppTheme style like the following.

```
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
```

Comment: It only changes hamburger icon color. Back arrow color remains unchanged.

Comment: @VishalKale I want to change both. Can you help?

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava Add `app:popupTheme` and `app:theme` to toolbar. And use 
`<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
`.

Answer (score 23):

In your AppTheme add this style.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
<item name="spinBars">true</item>
<item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

---

Answer (score 19):

Put this code in your activity

```
toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
```

Answer (score 11):

The following worked for me.

```
 <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
        </style>
```

Comment: its is the best and shortest method to change color of navigation indicator , thanks

Answer (score 2):

1: Go to directory `res` -> `themes.xml`

2: Inside:

```
<style name="Theme.YourAppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

add this line:
`<item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>`

you can add this to `themes.xml (night)` or you may change it according to your preferred style.