# How to give custom icon color for a single menu item in a NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using android NavigationView. I want to give seperate icon color for some items in the NavigationView, not for all items. I hope each icon have different color.  How can I do this?

Comment: You need to add the color in theme: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626488/change-the-color-of-navigation-drawer-indicator-icon

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

and the menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inbox"
            android:icon="@null"
            android:title="@string/inbox" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_start_end"
            android:icon="@null"
            android:title="@string/start_trip" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_map"
            android:icon="@null"
            android:title="@string/showmapview" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_allstudentlist"
            android:icon="@null"
            android:title="@string/allstudentlist" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@null"
            android:title="@string/settings" />
    </group>



</menu>
```

you can specify your icons for each menu

Comment: Thanks,I do it ,but the icons have a same color.if you set      app:itemIconTint="your color" attribute in NavigationView,the problem is still unsolved.Because the icons still have a same color.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Drawable/Mipmap resource for Icon, it depends on what colour those originally are in I assume. 
If you are importing the images into Android Studio through the menu as ActionBar icons those would all be in one colour based on what you selected as theme (Light/Dark)

Are your assets (drawables) having different colours?

Comment: I use drawable resource for icon in NavigationView menu item by " android:icon="@drawable/ic_home" ". But no matter what the icon is, the color is same.